# MySQL table queries extremely slow

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL 8.0.17 and I have a table with just 7 million rows defined like

```
CREATE TABLE `measurement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `field3` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `field4` double NOT NULL,
  `field5` double NOT NULL,
  `field6` double NOT NULL,
  `field7` double NOT NULL,
  `field8` double NOT NULL,
  `field9` double NOT NULL,
  `field10` double NOT NULL,
  `field11` double NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index2` (`field2`),
  KEY `index3` (`field3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7435062 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

and queries on it are extremely slow. For example,

```
select count(*) from measurement;
```

takes around 10 minutes. I have another table in the same database with roughly the same number of rows and columns where the same query takes 35 ms. When I do an `explain` on the above query I get

```
id|select_type|table             |partitions|type |possible_keys|key       |key_len|ref|rows   |filtered|Extra      |
--|-----------|------------------|----------|-----|-------------|----------|-------|---|-------|--------|-----------|
 1|SIMPLE     |measurement       |          |index|             |index3    |8      |   |7132937|   100.0|Using index|
```

Before I added the other two indices this query took 17 minutes. Everything was created using Django 3.1. When I try to `analyze` the table the result is

```
Table      |Op     |Msg_type|Msg_text|
-----------|-------|--------|--------|
measurement|analyze|status  |OK      |
```

Where do I need to look to figure out what my issue is?

Comment: did you try rebuild indexes - analyze table?

Comment: @Nikita - will try and update question.

Comment: Sadly `optimize table measurement` has been running for several hours now...

Comment: did you test the query after analyze finished? please add output of show table status and query profile (set profiling on)

Comment: Optimizing `count()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400451/optimize-mysql-count-query

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you have a slow disk, small ram and the main cache is too small.

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  SSD or HDD?

Without the secondary indexes, it had no choice but to read the entire table which was probably about 200MB?  But the buffer pool is only 16MB or 128MB (old defaults), hence "caching" was useless.

Moving to a much smaller secondary index (with 8-byte `DATETIME(6)` and 4-byte `INT`) was somewhat faster, but still too big to be cached.

I don't want to advise on the buffer_pool size without first knowing how much (or little) RAM you have and whether there are other processes running.

Comment: two minutes to count number of rows in 100MB index even if it reads data from hdd looks too much

Comment: @Nikita - I agree, hence the buffer_pool questions.  Also, are other queries running at the same time?  This would lead to more thrashing of I/O.